# Why does rollup treat my code as "external dependency"?

Tags: rollupjs

I'm learning to use [Rollup](http://rollupjs.org) in [this project](https://github.com/akauppi/jspm-trial/tree/rollup).

When doing:

```
$ npm run rollup

> @ rollup /Users/akauppi/Source/jspm-trial
> rollup -c rollup.config.js --output out/bundle.js --sourcemap true

Treating 'some' as external dependency
```

My output only has the entry point, not the files imported from it. Why would that be?

```
$ more dist/bundle.js
'use strict';

var some = require('some');

console.log(some.some); // 42
```

Details are available in the repo (link above).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems the import paths need to be relative, in order for Rollup to treat them as internal modules:

```
import {some} from "./some";
```

or use [rollup-plugin-includepaths](https://github.com/dot-build/rollup-plugin-includepaths) (I did not try).

References:

- [Integrate ES2015, Rollup in legacy 'AMD' project](http://fengshuo.co/2016/03/10/integrate-with-rollup-and-es2015-in-amd-project/) (blog post)
- [issue 104](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/104)

Comment: ` rollup-plugin-includepath` does help.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  It has s at the end.

Comment: yup, you're right. [unable to edit my initial comment]